# Apply group by on result of window function

Tags: mysql

I used window function to calculate each product's profit percentage

```
SELECT 
    productCode, productProfit, paymentDate, productName,
    productProfit/sum(productProfit)  OVER (PARTITION BY productCode) AS percent
FROM
    profit;
```

The output
[image]

The next step, I want to calculate AVG(percent). How can I it into the first statement?

The result will look like this
[image]

Comment: What would be expected output ? Add it in formatted text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way of calculating `percent` is bit weird. It seems that you are identifying contribution of particular transaction in overall profit.

Anyways, you can simply use your existing query's result-set as a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), and do a `Group By` using [`Year()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function, to calculate the [`Avg()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg):

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(dt.paymentDate) AS payment_date_year, 
  AVG(dt.percent) AS average_profit_percent 
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    productCode, 
    productProfit, 
    paymentDate, 
    productName,
    productProfit/sum(productProfit)  OVER (PARTITION BY productCode) AS percent
  FROM
    profit
) AS dt
GROUP BY 
  payment_date_year
```